# Suddenly, every test in our Rails 4 app fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake

My co-workers tell me these tests pass when they run them. But I just checked the code out from Bitbucket, and for me, the tests fail. I made sure that my machine has the same version as my co-workers:

Rails 4.2.4

Ruby 2.2.3

rake, version 10.4.2

After some pain with nokogiri, I was able to get "bundle install" to run.

But if I do this:

```
   bin/rake test
```

Every test fails:

27 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 27 errors, 0 skips

with an error that looks like this:

```
    6) Error:
    ProfilesControllerTest#test_#update:
    NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass


    Error:
    ProfilesControllerTest#test_#update:
    NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is an example of some failing code:

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class ProfilesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

      test '#update' do
        profile = profiles(:no_address_profile)
        login(profile)
        VCR.use_cassette('essex_street_ny') do
          patch :update, profile: {address: '15 Essex street, New York, NY, USA', zipcode: '10002'}
        end
        updated_profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(profile.user_id)
        assert_equal '15 Essex street, New York, NY, USA', updated_profile.address
        assert_equal '10002', updated_profile.zipcode
        assert_redirected_to root_path
      end

      test '#update with only zipcode' do
        profile = profiles(:no_address_profile)
        login(profile)
        VCR.use_cassette('only_10002_zipcode') do
          patch :update, profile: {zipcode: '10002'}
        end
        updated_profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(profile.user_id)
        assert_equal '10002', updated_profile.zipcode
        assert_redirected_to root_path
      end

      def login(profile)
        session[:user_id] = profile.user_id
      end
    end
```

So what is really happening here?

UPDATE:

If I do :

```
     rake db:fixtures:load
```

I get:

```
   rake aborted!
   NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to run migrations in your test environment. You can do that like so:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```